# Instance Variable getting reset to zero once gesture is over

Tags: ios, swift

```
@IBAction func OnRightSwipeGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translated = sender.translationInView(self.view);

    let diffTrans = (translated.y - previouslyTranslated.y) / 75;
    sum += diffTrans;
    print(sum);
    colorWheel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(sum);
    previouslyTranslated = translated;
}
```

In this function I add the difference in translation after every time its called. After I take my finger off the device however and try to make a new gesture, sum is reset to 0. Sum is declared at the top of the class, I am extremely confused...

Comment: why dont u log the sum variable at the end of the function and also add a switch case with cases as `uigesturestatebegan`, `uigesturestateended`

Comment: What is in there your `diffTrans`? If you get negative value second time, then it may set `sum` to 0.

Comment: i think your duffTrans is returning 0 as it return integer not float. define it as let diffTrans = (translated.y - previouslyTranslated.y) / 75.0;

Answer (score 0):

You should probably check the gesture recognizer's `state`, and only update your variable when it is equal to `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`.